# Ember UI not triggering Ember controller actions during testing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have quite an interesting problem.

We have Rails + Capybara performing integration tests with our Ember frontend.

The issue I'm having is, when running our `:Selenium` powered tests, *SOMETIMES* (and this is the crucial bit, it's sometimes), a UI element will be pressed and the Ember action will NOT fire.

So, **This is NOT** an ajax related issue. **I'm not** getting a data error. **Nor** an Ember error, **nor** a js error, **nor** a `Capybara::ElementNotFound` error.

The UI in question has loaded, Capybara then successfully clicks on the button, and then the Ember action is never called. It's not that it's taking too long to respond, it's simply not triggered.

I know this because I'm logging the Ember actions (`console.log()`) and can see it happen when it works, and not happen when it doesn't.

So, my theory is... Ember has loaded the UI before it's setup all the js to handle the actions. Could this be possible?

Comment: Could you share (part of) your testing code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicitly triggering the [run loop](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/run-loop/) in your tests?

Comment: hey @dv87. I've read about the runloop... but not sure where how and when I should interact with it??

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to tell, but generally it's wise to wrap user interactions in run loops (so a click which triggers a route change should be wrapped by `Ember.run(function() { /* Your code */ });`

Comment: thanks @dv87, but I'm running this within capybara, no js code explicitly executed, capybara simply simulates user interaction. I'ts all written in ruby.

Comment: Allrighty.. I'm not familiar with that toolkit but it might still be a runloop issue.. To test this, you could try pausing the test after entering a route (so the runloop has time to complete). More on http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/testing-ember-with-ember-rails/4162/8 . Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

It seems as if the Ember templates, and thus UI, will load BEFORE all methods in the `setupController` property in Routers is complete.

I don't really know enough about Ember to understand how and why this works like this, but I was able to fix this issue by doing the following:

1. At the end of all callbacks in `setupController` I set a controller property to true. 'controller.set('setupDone', true)'
2. In the template for that Route, I wrap the UI in a conditional `{{#if setupDone}}`